# React:Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Can someone please help me why this code showing me " **Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component**" error while refreshing the page?

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [course, setCourse] = useState({});
const router = useRouter();
const { slug } = router.query;

  //fetch course from backed using slug
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    loadSingleCourse();
   }, [slug]);

  const loadSingleCourse = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/course/${slug}`);
    setCourse(data);
    setLoading(false);
    //   console.log(data);
  };
```

I can access course state but Even after having loading state its throwing me error of state update on unmounted component. This is my render :

```
{loading ? (
        "Loading.."
      ) : (
        <>
          <div className="max-w-2xl px-6 py-16 mx-auto space-y-12">
            <article className="space-y-8 ">
              {/* <div>
              <img
                className="w-full h-72 rounded-xl shadow-xl"
                src={course.image.Location}
              />
            </div> */}
              <div className="space-y-6">
                <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold md:tracking-tight md:text-5xl text-accent">
                  {course.title}
                </h1>
                <div className="flex flex-col items-start justify-between w-full md:flex-row md:items-center dark:text-coolGray-400">
                  <div className="flex items-center md:space-x-2">
                    <img
                      src="https://source.unsplash.com/75x75/?portrait"
                      alt=""
                      className="w-4 h-4 border rounded-full dark:bg-coolGray-500 dark:border-coolGray-700"
                    />
                    <p className="text-sm">
                      {course.instructor.name} • {course.createdAt}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="dark:text-coolGray-500">
                <p>{course.description}</p>
              </div>
            </article>
            <div>
              <div className="flex flex-wrap py-6 space-x-2 border-t border-dashed dark:border-coolGray-400">
                <p className="px-3 py-1 rounded-md hover:underline bg-primary text-accent">
                  #{course.category}
                </p>
                <p className="px-3 py-1 rounded-md hover:underline bg-accent text-primary">
                  {course.lessons.length} Lessons
                </p>

                {/* Add Lession Modal */}
                <div>
                  <label
                    for="add-lesson-modal"
                    className="border-2 flex align-center items-center text-accent py-1 rounded-md px-2 cursor-pointer"
                  >
                    <svg
                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      className="h-5 w-5"
                      viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                      fill="currentColor"
                    >
                      <path
                        fill-rule="evenodd"
                        d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zm1-11a1 1 0 10-2 0v2H7a1 1 0 100 2h2v2a1 1 0 102 0v-2h2a1 1 0 100-2h-2V7z"
                        clip-rule="evenodd"
                      />
                    </svg>
                    Add Lesson
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    id="add-lesson-modal"
                    className="modal-toggle"
                  />
                  <div className="modal">
                    <div className="modal-box overflow-scroll">
                      <AddLessonForm
                        handleAdd={handleAddLesson}
                        values={values}
                        setValues={setValues}
                        uploading={uploading}
                        course={course}
                        uploadVideoText={uploadVideoText}
                        handleLessonVideo={handleLessonVideo}
                        uploadProgress={uploadProgress}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      )}
```

When I try to refresh its showing me:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

[Error image of render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVO0P.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax worked for me didn't know why loading state was not working!
I have also tried with some cleanup but nothing worked.

```
{course && 

<>
...
</>

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing something - the function and the export. I have also included an alternate way to render if loading is true:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const SomeComponent = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [course, setCourse] = useState({});
    const router = useRouter();
    const { slug } = router.query;

    //fetch course from backed using slug
    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        loadSingleCourse();
    }, [slug]);

    const loadSingleCourse = async () => {
        const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/course/${slug}`);
        setCourse(data);
        setLoading(false);
        //   console.log(data);
    };

    if (loading) {
        return (
            <>Loading...</>
        );
    }

    return (
        <>
            ...
        </>
    );
}

export default SomeComponent;
```

Comment: Is it export default stmt ??

Comment: that, and the function itself (line 4 in my code)

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that the error is due to using setState fn in `loadingSingleCourse` function.

Comment: no, that should be no problem at all :) - it is just the result of the missing function, I guess - because without that function and the default export, there can be no mounting.

Comment: thank you, please accept it as the correct answer too if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Its not my question man, I can not check it?

Comment: oh, my bad, i thought it is yours since you commented on it, sorry :)

Comment: No I was also searching for the mistake

Comment: I have default export at the end , I just didn't include on that

Comment: This is the full code link have a look if you can find anything?                              
  [Full code Link](https://github.com/DebanjanT/debug/blob/main/debug_1.js)

Comment: @DebanjanTewary looks good, maybe you really did not mount it somewhere? are you sure it is mounted in some other JSX?

Comment: @andyrandy You mean have I used this component in any other file?

Comment: yes, although the error should not even happen if the component is not even in use, but you never know...

Comment: @andyrandy But the thing is I am using nextJS, Its an page for displaying single course to instructor, I don't need to mount it to anywhere

Comment: oh, my bad - yeah, there should be no need to mount...